# C++ : Is class type const always a top-level const?

Tags: c++, constants, c++20

Here are the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
   int *x;
};

int main() {
   int b=100;
   A a;
   a.x = &b;
   const A &m = a; // clause 1 - Is this top-level const? 
   int *r = m.x; // *r has no const yet allowed. Is it due to reference m being top level const?
}
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `m.x` - the pointer - is const; you can't change it to point to something else (e.g. `m.x = nullptr;` won't compile). The object that `m.x` points to is not const; `*(m.x) = 42;` would compile.

Comment: What do you mean by top-level const?

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.type.qualifier#6

Comment: The contents of `A` are declared in the scope of `A`. The variables `a` and `m` are declared in the local scope of `main()`. There is nothing here that is at the top level. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int const ca = 24;
int a = ca;
```

You would expect this to compile right? And indeed it does. Here I initialized a integer with the value `24`.

You code is the same situation, except that instead of integer you have pointer to integer:

`m` is const so `m.x` is const. The `x` is const, i.e. `x` cannot be modified (via `m`). In stricter terms `m.x` is of type `int * const` i.e. constant pointer to integer.

```
int *r = m.x
```

Here you just initialize the pointer `r` with the value of the pointer `m.x`. The fact that `m.x` is const is not an issue. Both types without their top level cv are identical: pointer to (mutable) integer.

---

> `const A &m = a; // clause 1 - Is this top-level const?`

<del>Yes</del> Talking about top level const on references is strange indeed. A reference cannot be rebound. However if we are talking about the referenced type, i.e. `const A` then yes, it is top level. But then again talking about top level const is useful only on pointer types. E.g. `int *const cp` vs `const int *p`.

Comment: It is 'top-level const' how?

Comment: Top-level const indicate constness of the object itself while low level const appears in the base type of a compound type

Comment: Talking of "top level const" with *reference*  is a little "strange". Reference cannot be rebound.

Comment: i think some correction here - const A &m=a; Reference is always a low-level const. But m.x is int *const (constant pointer to int) which is top-level const. Hence changes are allowed e.g. int *r = m.x. So @bolov the statement const A &m = a; is not a top-level const.